# Split name into multiple parts in SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I cannot seem to find an existing post on splitting a string into the parts I require. I have a database field in SQL Server that contains the "LastName FirstName MI" (no commas just spaces delimiting each part of a person's name).  I have the following SQL to get the FirstName and Last, but cannot figure out how to get the Middle Initial or Middle Name.

Ex. Doe John B

```
SELECT
    RTRIM(LEFT([PATIENT_NAME], CHARINDEX(' ', [PATIENT_NAME]))) AS LastName,
    SUBSTRING([PATIENT_NAME], CHARINDEX(' ', [PATIENT_NAME]) + 1, LEN([PATIENT_NAME])) AS FirstName
FROM
    Clients
```

Results in:

- FirstName = John B
- LastName = Doe

How to just return the first name without the middle initial and get the 'B' as middle name from this string in this `SELECT` statement?

Comment: This article always make me giggle when dealing with names: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: What's your sql server version?

Comment: To piggyback on @Larnu's comment: What guarantee do you have that someone's name will be in the format you present? What do you expect to happen if someone's name is **not** in this format? What about someone with 2 last names (common in Hispanic countries) or no last name? I foresee problems in your future...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the number of elements you must extract from your string is fixed(3) you can use XML based split:

```
DECLARE @clients TABLE (PATIENT_NAME nvarchar(max));
INSERT INTO @clients VALUES 
 ('  Doe    John  B     ')
,('    Doe    Jane  C  ')
,(' Doe    Jill     ')

;WITH Splitted
AS (
    SELECT PATIENT_NAME as ORIGINAL_PATIENT_NAME
         ,REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(PATIENT_NAME)),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') as PATIENT_NAME
        ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ltrim(rtrim(PATIENT_NAME)),' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' '), ' ', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS Parts
    FROM @clients
    )
SELECT
     ORIGINAL_PATIENT_NAME 
    ,PATIENT_NAME
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS LAST_NAME
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[2]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS FIRST_NAME
    ,Parts.value(N'/x[3]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS MIDDLE_NAME
FROM Splitted
```

Results:

[image]

As you can see it works even with random-spaced names.

Answer (score 2):

You can either take the right 1 character, or reverse the string the take the first char.

```
SELECT RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM([Patient_Name])), 1) AS Middle_Initial

SELECT LEFT(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM([Patient_Name]))), 1) AS Middle_Initial
```

As for removing MI from your firstname string, I would either find the length of the string and take the left N-2 chars or I would charindex the space and then take that many chars.  To put it all together:

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(100) = 'Smith David M      ' 

--Clean the string of leading/trailing whitespace
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)) AS name_cleaned

--Find the first space to parse out the last name
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @name) AS first_space

--Select all chars before the first space
SELECT LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)), CHARINDEX(' ', @name)-1) AS last_name

--Find the next space, use the starting location as the previous space and add 1
SELECT CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 7) AS second_space

--Select all chars between the spaces
SELECT SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX(' ', @name)+1, CHARINDEX(' ', @name, 7) - CHARINDEX(' ', @name)) AS first_name

--Select the right most char for middle initial
SELECT RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)), 1) AS middle
```

Comment: Thank you, however the RIGHT([Patient_Name]) for some reason is not bringing  back anything.  I would have expected the B (perhaps there are spaces), I'll have to check.  Also how to remove the MI from the FirstName?

Comment: @DataCrypt Throw some trims on Patient_Name if you are getting whitespace back. I'll add something on how to remove MI from firstname.

Comment: Thanks again.  The SELECT RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(@name)), 1) AS middle works, but it's taking the first character of the firstname and using that as the Middle Initial when there is no MI.

Comment: @DataCrypt Dude, we aren't going to be able to code an idiot-proof solution for you. Names are hard and then can get very complicated. You have a starting point, so put in some leg work from here.

Answer (score 1):

You can REPLACE the space characters with period characters (.) and use PARSENAME().

Note that this would work for all 3 parts of the name, not just the middle initial.

Comment: How to do this in a SELECT statement?  I need to use eventually use the query in an UPDATE statement.  Thank you.

Comment: Nest the REPLACE function inside the PARSENAME function in your SELECT.

Comment: @DataCrypt I would be **very** careful if this is real data and you are going to update the value of `PATIENT_NAME`. Although my comment to the question, with the link to the article, was a little in jest, it is actually very true. It is impossible to make "safe" assumptions about every name in a dataset in the "real world".

Answer (score 1):

When using the CHARINDEX on the last name, you'll use it as the length of the substring. Then, on the FirstName, use it again as start position on the substring. Now, the trick on the Middle, on the CHARINDEX, you have to include the start position which will be the LEN minus the LastName CHARINDEX. this would gives you the second space which is the position you want to start with for taking the Middle Name.

See the example below :

```
DECLARE @tb TABLE (PATIENT_NAME varchar(250));
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES 
('Doe John B')

DECLARE 
    @LastName       INT
,   @Middle         INT 

SELECT 
    @LastName       =  CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME)
,   @Middle         =  CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME,  LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - CHARINDEX(' ', PATIENT_NAME))
FROM @tb


SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(PATIENT_NAME, 1, @LastName) LastName
,   SUBSTRING(PATIENT_NAME, @LastName, LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - @LastName) FirstName 
,   SUBSTRING(PATIENT_NAME, @Middle, LEN(PATIENT_NAME) - @Middle + 1 ) Middle  
FROM @tb
```

I have declared some variables to make things much readable, but you can do it without them.

Surely, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` are the easier approaches on taking the lastname and Middle Name. Along with using some helper functions such as `REVERSE` and `TRIM`, but I would prefer `PARSENAME` as a simpler and cleaner approach.
Here is an example :

```
SELECT 
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(PATIENT_NAME,' ','.'),3) LastName
,   PARSENAME(REPLACE(PATIENT_NAME,' ','.'),2) FirstName
,   PARSENAME(REPLACE(PATIENT_NAME,' ','.'),1) Middle
```

Comment: This PARSENAME statement brings back all fields as NULL.

Comment: @DataCrypt this means you have white space or double space, to check, use LEN() on the field, and check the number of characters you have with the spaces, then compare them with LEN see the differences. This would give you an insight on which method would be with your data